# detect cmd + c on mac to make copy work in angular app

Tags: angular, keyboard-shortcuts

I've worked on angular app and we can't copy on mac with cmd + C in the website. I tried with the code below. It works with metakey (cmd) alone and it copies. But it doesn't work with meta + c (keyCode 67). In fact, keyCode 67 alone is not detected. I tried to use keydown event due to a post i red. Here is the code :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { merge } from  'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { timer } from 'rxjs'
import { debounce } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class BindKeypressEvent {

onKeyPress($event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if($event.metaKey && $event.keyCode == 67 ) {
            alert('icciii');
            window.document.execCommand('copy');
        }
           
       // if(($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) && $event.keyCode == 86) {
       //     document.execCommand("paste");
       // }      
    }

private bindKeypressEvent(): Observable<KeyboardEvent> {
        const eventsType$ = [
            fromEvent(window, 'keydown')
        ];
        // we merge all kind of event as one observable.
        return merge(...eventsType$)
            .pipe(
                // We prevent multiple next by wait 10ms before to next value.
                debounce(() => timer(10)),
                // We map answer to KeyboardEvent, typescript strong typing...
                map(state => (state as KeyboardEvent))
            );
}

public bind() {
    this.bindKeypressEvent().subscribe(($event: KeyboardEvent) => this.onKeyPress($event));

}
```

If someone knows anything about these keycodes on mac. Thanks.

EDIT (event before not working too)

```
const eventsType$ = [
            fromEvent(window, 'keypress'),
            fromEvent(window, 'keydown')
        ];
```

EDIT :

Does not work neither :

```
onKeyPress($event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if($event.metaKey) {
        if ($event.key === 'c' )  {
            alert('icciii');
            window.document.execCommand('copy');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this is a better way then key capture: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event

Comment: i'm not sure because the event doesn't seem to trigger i think on mac.